# How is Longest Increasing Sub-sequence a special case of longest path in DAG?

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I read this statement in "Hitchhiker's guide to algorithms". But, I'm not able to visualize it as in a LIS problem all we have is a sequence of numbers. How can I modulate it as a graph problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine the problem of a 2D grid. You're on the bottom left square and you need to get to the top right square. Can you imagine an acyclic DAG out of this scheme?

Now imagine some of the squares are forbidden. Making squares forbidden may lead to a 'lock' (you might find yourself trapped), and now chosing **which paths to follow** is actually important.
In terms of graph, you can think of forbidding squares as *removing vertices*, and your goal is *go from the root to one specific node (the sink)*.

Now let's go back to the LIS. When solving the LIS, what you actually need to do is decide **which numbers you'll pick**, and which you won't. The restriction is that *whenever you pick one number, you can't pick any number which is **smaller** than this one* (you pick the numbers in order).

Now we can mix both things. Imagine that you'll build a graph out of your sequence of numbers:

- Every number will be a node.
- Number-node A has an edge to number-node B iff

  - B comes after A in the sequence
  - B is greater than A in value
- There's a special node **end**
- Every node has an edge to **end**

Every path on this graph is a valid *increasing subsequence*. The problem of finding the LIS is now the problem of finding the **longest path on this graph**.

Comment: Very nicely explained. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: This is a very great explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If we have an array of numbers, say 1, 5, 4, 8 for example. We can construct a DAG like the following.

- Add each number as a vertex.
- For each number vertex, add outgoing edges of weight 1 to all the greater numbers after it.
- Add a node S that has outgoing edges of weight 0 to all the number vertices.
- Add a node E that has incoming edges of weight 0 from all the numbers vertices.

Thus the Longest Increasing Subsequence problem turns into the Longest Path from S to E problem.

[image: LIC and DAG]

Comment: shouldn't there be an edge from 1->4 too ?